# I want to make a random number guessing game in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I want a higher or lower game using tkinter in the `def tookawhile():` from 0 too 1000 and I want it to go for 3 rounds. When round 3 is over I want it to say "Well done now go user as there is No game" where the text box is locked as the person cant edit it

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time
from tkinter import *
playing_game = False
def to_make_video():
    global btn1
    text_widget.configure(state='normal')
    msg = "People who are watching go hit that subscribe button and"+\
          " hit that like button also hit that little bell to turn on"+\
          " notifcations"
    text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
    text_widget.insert("end", msg)
    text_widget.configure(width=25, height=6)
    text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
    btn1.destroy()
    start_game()

def tookawhile():
 text_widget.configure(state='normal',height=4)
 text_widget.delete("0.0","end")
 text_widget.insert("end", "User lets play a game if you arent going to leave\nI have a number between 0 and 1000 in my memory chip can you guess it?")


def whyisthereanapp():
  text_widget.configure(state='normal',width=29,height=2)
  text_widget.delete("0.0","end")
  text_widget.insert("end","Well the creator released it by accident")
  text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
  btn.destroy()
  time.sleep(10)
  tookawhile()
def game_won():
    # When the button is pressed:
    global playing_game
    text_widget.configure(state='normal')
    playing_game = False
    text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
    text_widget.insert("end", "Why aren't you leaving?")
    text_widget.configure(width=23, height=1)
    text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
    btn.destroy()
    #btn2 = Button(title="I want to play")
    #btn2.pack()

def move_button():
    global playing_game
    # If the game is over stop moving the button
    if not playing_game:
        return None
    # Pick the next random position for the button
    numberx = random.randint(1, 600)
    numbery = random.randint(1, 470)
    btn.place(x=numberx, y=numbery)
    # After 500 milliseconds call `move_button` again
    # You can change the value to make it faster/slower
    root.after(200, move_button)

def start_game():
    # Start the game
    global playing_game
    btn.config(command=game_won)
    playing_game = True
    # Start the loop that keeps moving it to new random positions
    move_button()

def toplayagame():
  text_widget.configure(state='normal')
  text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
  text_widget.insert("end", "Well there is no game")
  text_widget.configure(width=21)
  text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
  btn1.destroy()
  btn.configure(text='Then why is there an application?',width=25,command=whyisthereanapp,background='Blue',foreground='Yellow',activebackground='Black')
  btn.place(x=349, y=470)
  
def pressed():
    global btn1
    # Ask the user why they are here
    text_widget.configure(state='normal')
    text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
    text_widget.insert("end", "Why are you here?")
    text_widget.configure(width=17)
    text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
    btn.place(x=190, y=470)
    btn.configure(text="To play a game", width=12, command=toplayagame)

    btn1 = tk.Button(root, bd=10, text="To make a video", bg="grey", fg="white",
                     activebackground="white", activeforeground="black",
                     height=1, width=15, command=to_make_video)
    btn1.place(x=1, y=470)

# Create a window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("There is no game")
root.geometry("1050x1400")

text_widget = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=10)
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.insert(tk.END, "Hello user")
text_widget.configure(state='disabled')

btn = tk.Button(root, bd=10, text="Hello", activebackground="black",
                activeforeground="white", bg="grey", fg="white", height=1,
                width=4, command=pressed)
btn.place(x=455, y=470)

# Run tkinter's mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not Exactly sure what you are asking but here are some things to help you. `text_widget.config(state=DISABLED)` would be to disable the text box.   `import random secretNumber = randint(1, 1000)` to get a random number between 1 and 1000.

Comment: @ruthless i want to make a higher or lower game in tkinter but the code has to go under ```def tookawhile():```

Comment: can you do the code in another format as it is all jumbled up please

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question. You've told us what you want but haven't explained what sort of help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is an a simple example that involves the terminal input but you can change it to be the gui input.

`

```
round = 1
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 1000)
'''text_widget.insert("end",str(secretNumber)) just to know what the number is 
for testing'''
for i in range(3):
    answer = int(input("Enter guess: "))
    if answer < secretNumber:
        print("Higher")
    elif answer > secretNumber:
        print("Lower")
    elif answer == secretNumber:
        print("Correct")
        break
text_widget.config(state=DISABLED)
```